# CXF write logs in specific file

Tags: grails, cxf, grails-2.0

in my application there are several web services implemented with the help of cxf framework. i want to log the incoming requests of each web service in separate files. e.g.

```
requests -> ws1 interface -> incomingWs1.log
requests -> ws2 interface -> incomingWs2.log
```

at the moment i know how to log incoming and outgoing messages with logging interceptors. this works fine, but with interceports i'm not able to define the output location for the logs. here is the sample using logging interceptors:

```
@WebService(endpointInterface = "at.pdts.cxf.HelloWorld")
@InInterceptors(interceptors = "org.apache.cxf.interceptor.LoggingInInterceptor") // this works!
@Logging(limit=16000, inLocation="<stdout>", outLocation="<logger>", pretty=true) // does not work!
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld { ...
```

after researching a while a found the logging annotation which provides the location settings i searched for, as you can see in the code sample above. the annation has no effect! i tried several location options, like

```
file:///c:/log.log
file:c:\log.log
<stdout>
```

i hope someone can point me in the right direction. i'm using the cxf framework 2.7.3 within a grails application with version 2.2.1.

Answer (score 1):

The `outLocation` attribute of `@Logging` annotation can be used to achieve this, however, the filename provided must be an absolute filename. An example is provided below:

```
@Logging(limit=16000, inLocation="<stdout>", outLocation="/absolute/path/to/file", pretty=true)
public class HelloWorldImpl implements HelloWorld { ...
```

Note that only absolute paths will work because a `URI` is being used to create the output file internally within the `AbstractLoggingInterceptor` class, as illustrated below:

```
public abstract class AbstractLoggingInterceptor extends AbstractPhaseInterceptor<Message> {
    public void setOutputLocation(String s) {
        ...
        } else {
            try {
                URI uri = new URI(s);
                File file = new File(uri);
                writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(file, true), true);
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                getLogger().log(Level.WARNING, "Error configuring log location " + s, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to use dynamic files whose name will be determined at runtime, you can extend `LoggingOutInterceptor` to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is very simple. if you want to use the logging annotation, you have to place it in the service endpoint interface. in the example i posted above the annotation belongs to the HelloWorld interface:

```
@Logging(limit=16000, inLocation="<stdout>", outLocation="<logger>", pretty=true)
public interface HelloWorld {
...
```

use file uris to log the soap messages in specific files, e.g. file:///c:/out.txt.